# Override the default number of posts to show for a single loop?

Tags: posts, loop

Is is possible to override the set # of blog posts to show per page (as defined under Reading Settings in the WordPress admin)? I want to make it so a custom loop that I am using will show an unlimited number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The argument that controls how many posts are shown in the query is posts_per_page

```
<?php query_posts( array( 
                         'post_type' => 'post',
                         'posts_per_page' => -1 ) 
      ); 
?>
```

Also to note is that there is a bug in the 3.0 branch which prevents the -1 integer from displaying all posts.  It is fixed in 3.1 but a workaround would be to use a very high number instead of -1

see:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15150

Comment: There's a typo in your parameter for posts_per_page. You have post_per_page instead of posts_per_page. (I tried to edit your post, but I don't have edit permissions). Many thanks!

Comment: **Avoid this function,** it's very bad for performance, causes lots of issues with pagination, etc. Use `pre_get_posts` to modify what gets shown on a page, and `WP_Query` if you want to fetch posts for other reasons. Never use `query_posts`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, change the query by adding

`<?php query_posts('post_type=post&numberposts=-1'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Eileen is right but it's better to use arguments as an array `<?php query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'numberposts' => -1 ) ); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.. I decided to add a custom variable and then catch that variable during `pre_get_posts` to set the `post_per_page` query_var:

```
function custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'post_per_page_override';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars_filter' );


add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rc_modify_query_get_design_projects' );
function rc_modify_query_get_design_projects( $query ) {

if( $query->query_vars['post_per_page_override'] == '3') {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '3');
    }
}
```

Then I went even further and make it get the exact amount you want to display in the custom query var:

```
function custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'post_per_page_override';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars_filter' );


add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rc_modify_query_get_design_projects' );
function rc_modify_query_get_design_projects( $query ) {

if( $query->query_vars['post_per_page_override']) {
        $customPPPlimit = $query->query_vars['post_per_page_override'];
        $query->set('posts_per_page', $customPPPlimit);
    }
}
```

Worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom loop, just specify `posts_per_page`, e.g.:

```php
$query = new \WP_Query( [ 'posts_per_page' => 100 ] );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    ......etc
```

You could set `posts_per_page` to `-1` for unlimited posts, but this is very bad practice. Instead set however many posts you think your server can serve without falling over so that your site doesn't go down if too many posts are created, 200 is a good upper limit.

Otherwise, use the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the parameters passed to queries:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 100 );
}
```

Note that this will set all queries to 100 pages, including feeds, REST API, XMLRPC, etc

In addition, some people will recommend `query_posts`, but this is bad practice and will cause lots of other issues